# Get <p> element to clip off text

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive webpage where text is loaded from a database.

```
<p style="width: 95%; font-size:13px; padding-right:20px; color:#babec5; margin-top: 3px;">
Just 7 days left ... Bob, Father's Day is only one week away, s...</p>
```

There is more text after the '...'. The p element has two lines vertically and I would like to be able to clip off any content but still fill up the `<p>` if the size of the page changes.

Comment: Give the element a fixed max height and set the `overflow` property to `hidden` and do yourself a huge favor by not using inline css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css `overflow: hidden;`, this will cut off the text.

If you want to have three dots at teh end, you can also use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` most modern browsers support that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Ftext-overflow

in order for it to work however you need a fixed height or max-height

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. What browser are you testing with? Also, please move all your styles into a separate stylesheet

Comment: Chrome. I only see one line though

Comment: For the ellipsis for multiline it must be formatted differently so I found this: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/  Thanks for leading me in the right direction. Might want to include this in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd just set the

style to include overflow:hidden

e.g.

```
p
{
  width: 95%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

here's a jsfiddle so you can see the effect (change bottom right panels size to see it in action)

http://jsfiddle.net/mdXCH/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this kind of css rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-props